# SAS: Joining dates to sum a column

Tags: date, sas

I have a problem coding in SAS.

I have a range of dates for a table A :

```
Date1          Date2    
01Jan2016     04Jan2016 
01Jan2016     08Jan2016 
04Jan2016     06Jan2016
```

and I have a reference table B:

```
Date          Value
01Jan2016     1
02Jan2016     0
03Jan2016     1
04Jan2016     1
05Jan2016     0
06Jan2016     1
07Jan2016     0
08Jan2016     1
```

I need to get the summation of the value column for each date range from table A.

With Table C:

```
Date1         Date2       Value
01Jan2016     04Jan2016   3
01Jan2016     08Jan2016   5
04Jan2016     06Jan2016   2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post what you've tried to align with SO rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a `proc sql`.

Building sample data:

```
data a;
    infile datalines dlm=' ';
    input date1 :date9. date2 :date9.;
    format date1 date2 date9.;
datalines;
01Jan2016 04Jan2016 
01Jan2016 08Jan2016 
04Jan2016 06Jan2016 
;
run;

data b;
    infile datalines dlm=' ';
    input date :date9. value;
    format date date9.;
datalines;
01Jan2016 1
02Jan2016 0
03Jan2016 1
04Jan2016 1
05Jan2016 0
06Jan2016 1
07Jan2016 0
08Jan2016 1
;
run;
```

And solution:

```
proc sql;
    create table c as
    select a.date1, a.date2, sum(value) as value
    from a, b
    where b.date between a.date1 and a.date2
    group by a.date1, a.date2;
quit;
```